# Issues after upgrading DB to mariaDB

Tags: mariadb, rundeck

I have recently built my rundeck server and created a DB using mariaDB and pointed rundeck to this. I followed the official documentation for this on the rundeck site. Since I have changed from the systemDB to mariaDB the service no longer starts.

My rundeck-config.properties file looks like this:
#loglevel.default is the default log level for jobs: ERROR,WARN,INFO,VERBOSE,DEBUG
loglevel.default=INFO
rdeck.base=/var/lib/rundeck

#rss.enabled if set to true enables RSS feeds that are public (non-authenticated)
rss.enabled=false

#change hostname here
grails.serverURL=http://IP OF SERVER:4440
dataSource.driverClassName=
dataSource.url = jdbc:mysql://IP OF SERVER/rundeck?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false
dataSource.username = DB User
dataSource.password = Password
grails.plugin.databasemigration.updateOnStart=true
autoReconnect=true

#to store projects on backend
rundeck.projectsStorageType=db

#Encryption for key storage
rundeck.storage.provider.1.type=
rundeck.storage.provider.1.path=keys

rundeck.storage.converter.1.type=jasypt-encryption
rundeck.storage.converter.1.path=keys
rundeck.storage.converter.1.config.encryptorType=custom
rundeck.storage.converter.1.config.password=7ee99cf09ffc59e7
rundeck.storage.converter.1.config.algorithm=PBEWITHSHA256AND128BITAES-CBC-BC
rundeck.storage.converter.1.config.provider=BC

#Encryption for project config storage
rundeck.projectsStorageType=db

rundeck.config.storage.converter.1.type=jasypt-encryption
rundeck.config.storage.converter.1.path=projects
rundeck.config.storage.converter.1.config.password=7ee99cf09ffc59e7
rundeck.config.storage.converter.1.config.encryptorType=custom
rundeck.config.storage.converter.1.config.algorithm=PBEWITHSHA256AND128BITAES-CBC-BC
rundeck.config.storage.converter.1.config.provider=BC

rundeck.feature.repository.enabled=true

Can anyone help with this

Comment: Hi! Could you share the service.log content at the moment of starting Rundeck?

Comment: Also, remember to set `dataSource.driverClassName` parameter to `org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver`, check the full example here https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/configuration/database/mysql.html#configuring-rundeck

Comment: In adition your `rundeck.storage.provider.1.type` is empty, set it as `rundeck.storage.provider.1.type=db`.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things here:

1. Your `dataSource.driverClassName` is empty, set it to `org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver`, check the full example [here](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/configuration/database/mysql.html#configuring-rundeck).
2. Your `rundeck.storage.provider.1.type` is also empty, set it as `rundeck.storage.provider.1.type=db`.

Comment: Configured all those and followed the rundeck guide but service still wont start.

Comment: Remember to share the service.log content to see what is happening :-)

Comment: These are the main errors that I can see

[2022-06-09T15:10:31,215] WARN  config.NavigableMap - Accessing config key '[filterNames]' through dot notation is deprecated, and it will be removed in a future release. Use 'config.getProperty(key, targetClass)' instead.
[2022-06-09T15:10:33,422] ERROR pool.ConnectionPool - Unable to create initial connections of pool.
java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not connect to address=(host=10.51.41.20)(port=4440)(type=master) : Socket fail to connect to host:10.51.41.20, port:4440. Connection refused (Connection refused)

Comment: For background my netowrk is behind a proxy, not sure if that matters.

Comment: Yeah, it seems a networking problem ("Socket fail to connect to host:10.51.41.20", make sure to reach the database instance from the Rundeck server. In addition, the MariaDB default port is the 3306, not the 4440 (" Could not connect to address=(host=10.51.41.20)(port=4440)(type=master)")

Comment: Thank you for the help, will go back and look at networking config see what I can find.

Comment: And remember that the MariaDB port is the 3306 :-) Check your Rundeck config (it seems to point to 4440) :-)